# How can I set text margins in a baposter document?

Tags: margins, templates, baposter

I have tried adding:

```
\usepackage[left=2.5cm,top=3cm,right=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}
```

But that gives the error:

```
! LaTeX Error: Option clash for package geometry.
```

So I'm guessing I can't use that package with baposter... Looking at the documentation (http://www.brian-amberg.de/uni/poster/baposter/baposter_guide.pdf), I was also hoping that linewidth could do the trick:

```
\begin{poster}{linewidth=0.8}
```

...but it doesn't seem to do anything either.

Any other way of setting margins with baposter?

**Update**

As requested, here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass[a0paper,portrait]{baposter}
\usepackage{lipsum}

%\geometry{left=2.5cm,top=3cm,right=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm} %sets margins for the whole page

\begin{document}

\begin{poster}{
grid=true,
linewidth=0.8  %doesn't change anything?
}
{}
{Poster Title}
{Poster Authors}
{}
\headerbox{box1}{name=box1,column=0}{
\lipsum[1]
}
\headerbox{box2}{name=box2,column=0,below=box1}{
\lipsum[1]
}
\headerbox{box4}{name=box4,span=2,column=1,row=0}{
\lipsum[1]
}
\headerbox{box5}{name=box5,span=2,column=1,row=0,below=box4}{
\lipsum[3]
}
\end{poster}

\end{document}
```

Comment: can you try `\geometry{left=2.5cm,top=3cm,right=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm}` instead of `\usepackage{}`? If this does not help, please make complete [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Comment: Document class xebaposter (CTAN) already loads geometry.  You might also want to use \pagestyle{empty}.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `baposter` class is useful for producing grid-based poster layouts.  It is flexible with respect to page sizes (up to A0), for content in up to 6 columns. `baposter` is not on CTAN but is available from here: http://www.brian-amberg.de/uni/poster/. A short, but adequate, 5 page manual is available and several examples have been posted for the guidance of users.

Setting the page margin is a class option for the `baposter` package (see page 3 of the manual). Therefore, the usage syntax is `\documentclass[margin=<length>]{baposter}`, where `<length>=`a typical value passed to `geometry` such as 25mm. 
The default page margin is 15mm.

The following two examples illustrate the usage of the margin option. The example on the left sets the margin at 25mm, while one on the right sets it at 125mm.  The resulting output is displayed against a background grid produced using the `eso-pic` package. `baposter's` showframe option (which presumably is also passed to geometry) is used to show the poster borders against the background grid. The margins (125mm) for the poster on the right are clearly larger than the margins (25mm) of the poster on the left. I cannot explain why the measurements generated by `eso-pic` do not correspond the the margins set for `baposter`, therefore this just serves to illustrate that the margins are indeed variables that can be set using the `margin=<length>` class option.

[image: Comparison of 25 and 125 mm margins]

This is the code used to produce the poster with 125mm margins. Note that the poster background is set to none so as to show the grid generated by `eso-pic`. The colored background can be restored by commenting out `eso-pic`, removing the verbatim around the `\background` code and changing `background=none` to `background=user` in the poster options.

```
\documentclass[a0paper,portrait,showframe,margin=125mm]{baposter}
%a0 paper = 84.1 x 118.9 cm
%baposter is not on CTAN. Get it from here:  http://www.brian-amberg.de/uni/poster/
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{helvet} %choose a sans serif font
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault} % replace the default font
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage[pscoord=true,grid,gridunit=mm,gridBG,gridcolor=green!50, subgridcolor=gray!25]{eso-pic}

\begin{document}

\begin{comment} %to turn on the background change the background option to ``user'' and comment out begin{comment} end{comment}
\background{
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]%
    %the poster background color
    \fill[fill=green!50] (current page.north west) rectangle (current page.south east);
    %the header
    \fill [fill=orange!50] (current page.north west) rectangle ([yshift=-\headerheight] current page.north east);
  \end{tikzpicture}
}
\end{comment}

\begin{poster}{
%general options for the poster
  grid=false,
  columns=3,
  colspacing=4.2mm,
  headerheight=0.08\textheight,
  background=none, %user or none or plain
  eyecatcher=true,
%posterbox options
  headerborder=closed,
  borderColor=blue,
  headershape=rectangle,
  headershade=plain,
  headerColorOne=blue,
%  headerColortwo=yellow!42, %is used when the header background is shaded
  textborder=rectangle,
  boxshade=plain,
  boxColorOne=white,
%  boxColorTwo=cyan!42,%is used when the text background is shaded
  headerFontColor=white,
  headerfont=\Large\sf\bf,
  linewidth=1pt
}
%Do not change the layout of the following items, although title and author can span multiple lines
%The logo on the left = eyecatcher
{
  \includegraphics[height=0.75\headerheight]{example-image-a}
}
%the poster title
{Title}
%  the author(s)
{Author}
%The logo on the right
{
  \includegraphics[height=0.75\headerheight]{example-image-b}
}

%Poster content

\begin{posterbox}[name=box1,span=1,column=0,row=0]{Box1}
\lipsum[1]
\end{posterbox}

\begin{posterbox}[name=box2,span=1,column=0,below=box1]{Box2}
\lipsum[1]
\end{posterbox}

\begin{posterbox}[name=box3,span=2,column=1,bottomaligned=box2]{Box3}
\lipsum[1]
\end{posterbox}

\end{poster}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the [anysize](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/anysize) package.

Add it to your preamble with

```
\usepackage{anysize}
```

than, also in the preamble, adjust the margin you wanted with

```
\marginsize{left}{right}{top}{bottom}
```

Comment: I've added a complete example, could you tell me where \marginsize should go? If I add it right after \begin{document} I get the error "Paragraph ended before \marginsize was complete."

Comment: Put it in the preamble too. Sorry for not mentioning it before.

Comment: I get the same error if I put it in the preamble. Also, even if I only add \usepackage{anysize}, it messes up the layout, so I'm not sure that package can be used with the baposter class.

Comment: @kormak Stick to using `\geometry{<setting>}`. Don't use `anysize`. It is just not worth it.